# setOnClickListener returns right position but wrong item

Tags: java, android, listview

I lost a whole day trying to figure out how to make this work.
I successfully set a custom adapter and my `ListView`.
The problem is that I get the right position of the item I click, but the item is always the last one in the list.
What's more is that I'm calling all of this inside another thread to execute a PostCall.

I tried following other examples, also of course following from the official developer resources, but I can't get a clue of what I am doing wrong.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            ListView serviceList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            String[] menu = result.split("_");
            ListaMenuActivity adapter = new ListaMenuActivity(ListaCibo.this, menu);
            serviceList.setAdapter(adapter);
            serviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(ListaCibo.this, String.valueOf(position) + parent.getAdapter().getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

I also tried using `parent.getItemAtPosition()`, also using the View, always same result.

**EDIT**
Here it is the code of my Adapter
    public ListaMenuActivity(Activity context, String[] itemname) {
        super(context, R.layout.menu_custom, itemname);

```
    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_custom, null,true);


    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ingredienti);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.vegan);
    try{
        if(itemname[position]!="Medium Text") {
            Log.e("basd", itemname[position]);
            String [] elems = itemname[position].split(", ");
            txtTitle.setText(elems[0] + ", " + elems[2]);
            extratxt.setText(elems[1].replace("-", ", "));

            if(!elems[3].equals("1")) {
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.leaf);
                vegan.setImageBitmap(icon);
            }
            desc_piatto = elems[4];
            nome_foto = elems[5];
            nomepiatto = elems[0];
        }
    } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return rowView;

}
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return nomepiatto + "," +nome_foto + "," + desc_piatto;
}
```

Comment: show your complete code.

Comment: Post your adapter.

Comment: Added the code of the adapter

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list have complete and proper data and if you are getting right position then you can directly fetch the value from the list with the use of position you get. Try below snippet

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {               
        String data = menu[position];
        Toast.makeText(ListaCibo.this, String.valueOf(position) + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: Ok, this way it works but..is there any reasong why my code doesn't work?
Because this is a way to avoid the problem, but i would like to have it working the way it should....
Thanks for pointing out this other way anyway, I will use it until I can get it to work properly.

Comment: Your answer is just a workaround to get the job done. It does not answer why it didn't work in the first place. Also I am quite sure that the listview is gonna break when there is sufficiently large data and scrolled rapidly. Also the OP is tightly coupling ``getView`` and ``getItem`` methods which is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea to set something inside getView and after that get it inside getItem().

That how your code works (example)

1. You see on the screen 4th and 5th items of the list
2. Adapter's getView called for position = 4
3. You set adapter global varibales desc_piatto, nome_foto, nomepiatto and to data of item number 4
4. Immediately getView called for item with position 5
5. You set global varibales to data of item 5
6. You call getItem from onItemClick, it returns last values of Adapter's global variables.

This is wrong use of Adapter's getItem. Read something about how ListView inflate views and about Adapter lifecycle

P.S. Use lowerCamelCase for variable naming and use ViewHolder for adapter

**EDIT:**
MUCH better, but not the best solution

```
class YourAwesomeObject {

    String[] elems = null;

    public YourAwesomeObject(String inputString) {
        elems = inputString.split(", ");
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return elems[0] + ", " + elems[2];
    }

    public String getExtraTxt() {
        return elems[1].replace("-", ", ");
    }

    public boolean isShowImage() {
        return !elems[3].equals("1");
    }

    public String getDescPiatto() {
        return elems[4];
    }

    public String getNomeFoto() {
        return elems[5];
    }

    public String getNomePiatto() {
        return elems[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getNomePiatto() + "," +getNomeFoto() + "," + getDescPiatto();
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_custom, null, true);


    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ingredienti);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.vegan);
    try {
        if (itemname[position] != "Medium Text") {
            Log.e("basd", itemname[position]);
            YourAwesomeObject item = getItem(itemname[position])
            txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
            extratxt.setText(item.getExtraTxt());

            if (item.isShowImage()) {
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.leaf);
                vegan.setImageBitmap(icon);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public YourAwesomeObject getItem(int position) {
    return new YourAwesomeObject(itemname[position]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess i start to see the problem but..I still don't get how I can fix this to make it work this way. 
Should I just take my data from menu and use them directly without going back and forth?

Comment: Thank @Romadro, I think I managed to solve. Since I already have menu there, I'll get my strings from there, even though it's not the most elegant solution, is the only one that works right now.

Comment: @Andrea if you don't want to use wrapper YourAwesomeObject, so use easiest and 100% right solution of Sumit Jha

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write your `getItem` as :

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    String [] elems = itemname[position].split(", ");
    return elems[0] + "," +elems[5] + "," + elems[4];
}
```